# Looking for neat way to describe a statement to avoid getting that message

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

The script works to determine the result of the "average true range" that required to cover only the regular market hours, excluding extended market data.  I'm looking for a proper way to describe this statement below.

```
float range = 0.0
if time("1440", session.regular)
    range:=atr(150)
```

The function result looks fine. But after running the script, it shows this advice in the console section:

```
line 63: The function 'atr' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when a built-in function is missing data due to under `if` statement call. Move the `atr` function calc to global scope as in the example below:

```
float range = 0.0
float atrRange = atr(150)
if time("1440", session.regular)
    range := atrRange
```

Comment: That's not correct!. I tried the same method as you presented before. Here's the case, I don't wanna include the extended market hours data in the calculation. In which, your script is included the extended hours in the calculation, but skipping to be not apparent in extended market hours. Did you get what I meant? Please compare the results of mine and yours to realize the difference. Thank you

Comment: Yeap, the final output is different, bc atr function calc constantly the latest 150 bars on the chart. In your example you exclude the extended hours from the calcs, so atr function is missing that data and that why you see the warning message in the console. Its only a warning about missing data and your script compiles with no problem

Comment: Yes, I wanted my code to skip the data out of range the regular session, so the system shows a message that informs there's data has not placed in the calculation. Okay, that makes sense. Thank you so much!